# Initialising an array using different array

Tags: python

I have a code that goes as:-

```
.....
path = 'path_to_csv_file';
file=open(path, "r")
reader = csv.reader(file)
y=np.empty((7000,1))
j=0
for line in reader:
    y[j]=line[0]
    j+=1

....

targets=np.zeros([7000,1,10])
```

Now, in the first array of targets, I want the `y[0]`th index to store 1 (`y[0]` stores integers from `0-9`). For that, I wrote:-

```
targets[0,0,y[0]]=1
```

But I get an error:-

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

When I print `y[0]`, I get:-

```
[6.]
```

as the output. What I think is that it's not an integer, so that's probably the source of my error, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `print(y[0])` and show us results. In general there's nothing wrong in `targets=np.zeros([7000,1,10])` and `targets[0,0,y[0]]=1`. Just hardcode y[0] to try (for example `y=[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]]`). The most likely the error is in reading `y` from file.

Comment: @Karls I've already shown the result for `print(y[0])`. It gives me `[6.]`

Comment: Ah ok, I see. And what is the content of your csv file?

Comment: @Karls It goes like `6,0,0,0......`. The answer below works by the way, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `dtype=int`?

```
y=np.empty((7000,1), dtype=int)
...
targets=np.zeros(([7000,1,10]), dtype=int)
```

You can check more on the documentation on the usage of [numpty.empty](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) and [numpty.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html#numpy.zeros)

Comment: @AnkitKumar In case it helped, mark the answer as accepted so anyone else with the same question can understand the answer worked out

Comment: Ya, there's a time limit before which i can't accept it, I was just waiting for that